# Is there a nice way to convert List<List<List<Integer>>> to List<List<List<String>>> w/o 3 nested loops?

Tags: java

Basically if I have some mapping bifunction is there a shortcut for this kind of operation (so I won't have to write 3 nested loops)?

Comment: You could have written the loops faster than writing this question...

Comment: I am trying to write it using streams in an answer below. And quite honestly: write the loops.

Comment: The nicest way would be not to have a triple nested `List` in the first place. That's not something that happens by accident.

Comment: Indeed, a `List<List<List<?>>>` is a very bad smell. This should most probably be refactored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List<List<List<String>>> collect = list
            .stream()
            .map(a -> a
                    .stream()
                    .map(b -> b
                            .stream()
                            .map(String::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I have the same code but probably am missing a parenthesis somewhere but can't find it ... this is unreadable... +1

Comment: 3 loops vs. 3 streams.. I see no difference, really.

Comment: Streams are more concise actually (if you write 3 loops you'll have to name a variable `intList` and `stringList` which is really bad).

Comment: Streams are also slower. While the for-loop has been optimised until the patina has been removed, streams have massive overheads for here, little to non-existent benefit. Also, really? You have to name some variables, which is really bad? I see you naming variables `a` and `b` above, I'm shocked.

Comment: @ifly6 not by *that much* slower to actually care in this case, but this stream solution is also less readable then the for loops probably, which does not happen too often with stream-api

Comment: Guys, this is 1 minute solution, what do you want? I don't care about variables names and I know that it's not an ideal solution, to use it or not to use is fully up to the question owner.

Comment: jahra, I upvoted your answer. I think the one-minute solution isn't poor, isn't bad, etc. It's a good solution that solves the problem. It's just that streams here are utterly unnecessary, and the strange post-Java8 aversion to for-loops that has gripped developers too is unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to use a recursive method that goes down the tree of lists and once it finds a list of something that's not a list (in your case an Integer) transforms it to a String:

```
public static List<?> mapToString(List<?> list) {
  return list.stream()
             .map(x -> {
                    if (x instanceof List) return mapToString((List) x);
                    else return String.valueOf(x);
                  })
             .collect(toList());
}
```

Note that it would work for a `List<List<List<List<List<List<Integer>>>>>>` if you fancy that kind of horror.

The downside is that it's not type-safe as is, so you need a cast.

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
  List<List<List<Integer>>> input = new ArrayList<> ();
  input.add(new ArrayList<> ());
  input.add(new ArrayList<> ());

  input.get(0).add(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
  input.get(1).add(Arrays.asList(3, 4));

  List<List<List<String>>> result = (List<List<List<String>>>) mapToString(input);
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find an equivalent, but type safe, solution but the problem with generic type is that you can't overload the method due to the type erasure. I believe this is the cleanest solution you can find. (Well cleaner than the original list ;) )

Comment: I was working on exactly the same answer. However you were faster :)) +1

Comment: @assylias impossible not to update a recursive lambda!